# how to broadcast a message to specific user using Openfire?

Tags: android, broadcast, openfire

How to broadcast a message to specific user using [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

**Scenario:** i want to broadcast a message to only that user whose credit balance is less then 100.
I have looked at [broadcast](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) and [message of the day(MOTD)](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) plug-in of [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Broadcast plug-in used to send a broadcast message to all and to particular group.and MOTD plug in is used to send a message to everyone when user comes online.

I searched on net but didn't get anything.

Any suggestion and advice will be appreciated . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can register a special account on your openfire server that would send all these messages. And send it in an ordinary way.

If you want this ability in your custom plugin you can do it as follows:

```
packet.setTo(userJid); // packet - is the message you want to send
ComponentManagerFactory.getComponentManager().sendPacket(this, packet);
```

Comment: how do i register that **special account**? i have already created a user(admin) in openfire

Comment: in openfire admin page: User/Groups -> Create New User

Comment: what the meaning of ordinary way, can you be more specific?
because in openfire admin page  i didn't find any option to send a message

Comment: you can login to openfire as your special user with any xmpp client (for example via spark) and send this message

Comment: i am using openfire but still i didn't get the option of send message. where do i get this option.please make it clear to me.